# Don't know how to reflection oneof filed

Tags: c++11, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message defined something like this

```
message Foo
{
 oneof test  //oneof field
    {
        int32 a = 1;
        MM b = 2;
    }
}

message MM
{
   string  str =1;
}
```

how i reflect of oneof  filed in protobuf

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, you handle a message with oneof the same way you would a message without:

```
message Foo
{
  int32 a = 1;
  MM b = 2;
}
```

Oneof is largely transparent to reflection, and doesn't affect the wire format. Its effect is that the generated setter code automatically clears other members of a oneof whenever one is set.

Now, if you care about oneofs for some reason, there's `Descriptor::oneof_decl` that allows you to enumerate them, `Descriptor::FindOneofByName`, and `FieldDescriptor::containing_oneof` (if you are working your way from the field up). With `OneofDescriptor` in hand, you can find its name and enumerate its fields, and that's pretty much it.